# Permission error when setting SSRS report parameters in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services

experts,

I'm inheriting a C# script to render a SSRS report. The script throws the following exception when it tries to set the report parameters ( serverReport.SetParameters(parameters): )

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportServerException: The permissions granted to user 'domainName\userName' are insufficient for performing this operation.

However, I am able to execute the report on the report manager without any problems. For Datasource setup, I selected "Credentials stored securely in the report server", filled in the above username (domainName\userName) and the password fields, and checked the box "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source". The report runs successfully on the report server.
Additonal info: The processing mode for the report viewer is set to remote in the C# script (reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote).

I don't understand why the credential works when executing the report on the report server, but not when accessing it through the C# script. I'm very new to C# and any help and info will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

It turned out that additional permission is needed for the report on the report server. After the DBA granted the account access to the report folder, the problem is solved.